# Return distinct nodes in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-grouping

I need help on how to loop for each unique node "set". The result I expect are unique sets. I've tried many different ways but nothing. It seems that I'm always getting all results, or none.

```
 <Res>
        <ResQ>
            <set>
                <No>1</No>
                <Desc>test</Desc>
                <Num>123</Num>
            </set>
            <set>
                <No>2</No>
                <Desc>test</Desc>
                <Num>111</Num>
            </set>
            <set>
                <No>3</No>
                <Desc>test</Desc>
                <Num>100</Num>
            </set>
        </ResQ>
    </Res>
    <Res>
        <ResQ>
            <set>
                <No>1</No>
                <Desc>test</Desc>
                <Num>333</Num>
            </set>
            <set>
                <No>2</No>
                <Desc>test</Desc>
                <Num>123</Num>
            </set>
            <set>
                <No>3</No>
                <Desc>test</Desc>
                <Num>555</Num>
            </set>
        </ResQ>
    </Res>
```

I've tried this but with no desired results.

```
<xsl:key name="keyTest" match="//set" use="concat(No, '+', Desc,'+',Num)"/> 

<xsl:for-each select="//set[generate-id(.) = generate-id(key('keyTest', concat(No, '+', Desc,'+',Num))[1])]" >
        <xsl:call-template name="row">
                    <xsl:with-param name="rb" select="No" />
                    <xsl:with-param name="desc" select="Desc" />
                    <xsl:with-param name="number" select="Num" />
         </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: You have got a lower-case `num` in your `generate-id` expression. Is that a typo in your question? If not, it would affect the results! You are also missing an opening square bracket `[` before the `1`.

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that. Its just a question typo :)

Comment: You've also got some mismatched brackets. On the right-hand side of the expression, you have 3 opening brackets, but two closing ones.... It should be `generate-id(.) = generate-id(key('keyTest', concat(No, '+', Desc,'+',Num))[1])`

Comment: Thanks. I've changed it :) Still, I cant get desired result.

Comment: Could you please amend your question to show the desired results, otherwise it may be a bit tricky to help. It might be worth pointing out that all your current "sets" are unique based on the `No`, `Desc` and `Num`. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*If* two sets are considered equals when they have the same `Num`, you should use just that element in both the key declaration and its use (otherwise, I didn't understand the question and my answer is useless):

```
<xsl:key name="keyTest" match="//set" use="Num"/>
...
<xsl:for-each select="//set[generate-id(.) = generate-id(key('keyTest', Num)[1])]" >
    <xsl:call-template name="row">
        <xsl:with-param name="rb" select="No" />
        <xsl:with-param name="desc" select="Desc" />
        <xsl:with-param name="number" select="Num" />
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:for-each>
```